# How can I change the merge sorting so that only positive elements are sorted?

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

How can I change the merge sorting so that only positive elements are sorted? With any of my changes, the sorting, if it does not move the negative elements, then the positive shuffles incorrectly

```
def merge_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1: 
        mid = len(arr)//2 
        left = arr[:mid] 
        right = arr[mid:]
        merge_sort(left) 
        merge_sort(right) 
        i = j = k = 0
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right): 
            if left[i] < right[j]:
                arr[k] = left[i]  
                i+=1 
            else:
                arr[k] = right[j] 
                j+=1 
            k+=1 
        while i < len(left):
            arr[k] = left[i] 
            i+=1
            k+=1
        while j < len(right): 
            arr[k] = right[j] 
            j+=1
            k+=1
```

Input

[57, 16, -70, -66, -59, -18, 43, -26, -99, 41]

Should output this

[16, 41, -70, -66, -59, -18, 43, -26, -99, 57]

If I set the condition that the replacement is only if it is greater than zero, it turns out like this

[57, 43, -70, 41, 43, 57, 16, -70, 16, 57]

Comment: Input [57, 16, -70, -66, -59, -18, 43, -26, -99, 41]

Should output this
[16, 41, -70, -66, -59, -18, 43, -26, -99, 57]

If I set the condition that the replacement is only if it is greater than zero, it turns out like this
[57, 43, -70, 41, 43, 57, 16, -70, 16, 57]

Comment: Do you *need* to integrate the sign thing into the sort? I think it would be simpler to separate the two things, i.e., extract the positives, sort them, and put them back in

Comment: If this is the only way out, then you will have to do this. I thought it was possible to add some condition to the sorting itself so that it only works with positive numbers.

Comment: Other sorting algorithms would be probably easier to adapt, bubble sort for instance

Comment: Yes, I know, I was given the task to adapt the selection and merge. selection sort was easy to adapt, but by merging I don't understand how...

Answer (score 0):

Keep i/j/k on the indexes of the positive values in their respective lists. So instead of starting at 0 and advancing with `+= 1`, search for the position of the next positive value.

I suggest to write a helper function that takes an index and a list and returns the index after skipping negative values.